# Replacing abstract base class with interface in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

I have an abstract base class with a single abstract method that I would like to get rid of. I would like to introduce a new interface with that method and make all existing subclasses to implement that interface rather than extending the base class.

From:

```
public abstract class Base {
  public abstract Foo getFoo();
}

public class Concrete extends Base {
  public Foo getFoo() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
}
```

To:

```
public interface Base {
  Foo getFoo();
}

public class Concrete implements Base {
  public Foo getFoo() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
}
```

I have tried to inline the baseclass without success, created the interface manually, pulling member and then delete the then empty base class, but I can't seem to get IntelliJ to complete this operation automatically.

Any suggestions on how I can solve this?

Comment: Hmm, you mention some manual steps you're willing to take but that you want the final one to be automatic?  Could you make your request more specific?  I mean, you've tried "extract interface", right?  I know that won't automatically change an abstract class to a Base though.

Comment: The reason intellij *probably* can't do exactly what you're asking for is that it wouldn't know what to do with the implemented methods in `Base`.  If Base becomes an interface, it wouldn't compile anymore because the implemented methods would have to go somewhere.

Comment: Ideally I don't want to do any manual steps, I just tried it as a work-around. I did try to use extract interface. With that followed a dialogue which seemed to offer what I wanted; Idea offers to try to replace usage of existing base class with interface, but it cannot change any of them for unknown reasons. Base is without implemented methods except for this single abstract one I want to pull up.

Answer (score 2):

I realise now that I managed to fool myself into thinking this was an IDEA problem. Rather it is related to the abstract type I tried to inline being used in quite a few generics references, i.e.

```
final MyMapping<Base, String>  = (...)
```

IDEA cannot guess what I would like to do with all these generic references. These must be resolved manually and apart from that the following does work. I start off with:

```
public abstract class AbstractSomething {
    public abstract void foo();
}

public class ConcreteSomething extends AbstractSomething {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Then I add:

```
public abstract class AbstractSomething implements Something {..}
```

and alt-enter on Something choosing to add that interface. I then refactor->pull members up and confirm to move the abstract method to the Something interface, the result being:

```
public interface Something {
    void foo();
}
public abstract class AbstractSomething implements Something {
}
```

With the cursor blinking on AbstractSomething in ConcreteSomething, ctrl+alt+n to inline superclass. AbstractSomething is a goner and I am left with

```
public class ConcreteSomething implements Something {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

You just gotta love this IDE, it is always smarter than I am.

Answer (score 1):

Type Alt+Enter on the name of the superclass and invoke Convert class to interface.

This quick fix is provided by the "Abstract class may be interface" inspection which is enabled by default in "No highlighting, only fix" mode. But if you have disabled it, you will need to enable it again